# Qt Creator 3.5.1 stdin for command line with Deploy to Remote Linux Host

Tags: qt-creator, cross-compiling, remote-debugging

following
[[Qt Creator stdin for command line with Deploy to Remote Linux Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869281/qt-creator-stdin-for-command-line-with-deploy-to-remote-linux-host/11887156][1])

"I found out that there is no way to provide stdin to an app launched by qt creator from within the IDE.
I did try a few things and it looks like a named pipe works just fine. Luckily it’s included with Busybox so it’s on my board.
To use it you launch the app remotely from Qt Creator using the ‘Alternate executable on device’ option under ‘run settings’ and pipe the last line of the named pipe to your c++ program expecting stdin. So your ‘Alternate executable on device looks like:"

```
tail -f mypipe | /home/prog//test
```

this is not working for Qt creator 3.5.1 based on qt 5.5.1
when running
run settings->Alternate executable on device: tail -f mypipe | /home/prog//test

getting back

**Process tail -f mypipe | /home/prog//test created; pid = xxxx**

**Cannot executable tail -f mypipe | /home/prog//test: No such file or directory**

I can run the program using ssh with out any problem ( using stdin or include using "mkfifo mypipe" and "tail")

tried different syntax with same result:

- '...'
- setting run settings->working directory: target path
- setting run settings->arguments: -qws
- tail -f mypipe | /home/prog//test -qws
- /home/prog/; tail -f mypipe | ./test -qws
- any other combination

it look like QT creator can only handle the syntax using only the exe

- Alternate executable on device: /home/prog//test

what I am doing wrong, syntax? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solve it using different approch
Using argv to send either cin or pathway to fifo file.
Then using ssh remotly with echo command > myfifofile. 
My code do the rest 
Reading from file or cin

Hope this help